# Couldn't find 'aapt' tool! You may need to update your Android SDK, including platform tools

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, trigger.io

I am developing mobile application using trigger.io tool. While running the application in the triggerio plat form it giving error as couldn't find "aapt.exe" tool. It was suggesting to update android sdk. I updated android sdk and plat form tools yet the same error displaying. Please suggest need ful. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: got the same issue - was running fine until the latest update.

Comment: I too am getting the same error, I have sent support emails but no response

Comment: Im not a python expert but it looks as if the python script is looking in a directory aapt when aapt is not in a directory, so if you change android_tasks.py for the aapt to not look for aaot in a directory it will find it but then you get  or at least I get an "error code 5 [access denied]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the same issue, solved it by changing "platform_version": "v1.4.47" in config.json

Comment: Shouldn't having just v1.4 be enough?

Comment: Version 1.4 is like the default "latest" version, so when you set it to version 1.4 its like setting it to the newest or in this case v1.4.48.

Answer (score 0):

So again from what I can tell this is a problem with the python script that calls aapt.

When you look at the script it points only to aapt, this means its looking for a directory and not the aapt.exe file itself so the first thing that happens is

1) forge says it cant find the aapt directory, this is why you are getting the error message "cant find aapt tool"

2) by adding the directory you would get the access denied because then the script is trying to run all these commands on just the directory (this was the problem I ran into), by making the change below you do not need to create a directory, just leave everything how it is but add the exe and it should work

After doing some testing I found that by adding .exe to the pythong script in android_tasks.py the build was able to run successfully

if you look on line 35 of android_tasks.py and change 'appt' to 'appt.exe' it should build for you

this is what it looks like for me

```
path.join(sdk, 'build-tools', '*','aapt.exe')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the help. By adding extension the error has fixed. But emulator unable to load the current running application. It have continuously display "android" text. I couldn't guess what is the actual problem ?

Comment: That might be just the emulator, its very slow even trigger.io recommends using a device as its much faster.. but if you must use an emulator and don't mind the version being 2.3 you can try bluestack, its very fast as an emulator for android and trigger.

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain more about bluestack. How can I use bluestack?

Comment: Bluestacks is just android 2.3, its built to allow people to download and play android games and apps on their desktops but at the end of the day its just the android emulator. So when its opened and you run forge it will run the app in bluestacks.

http://www.bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

We made a change to fix this issue in our v1.4.49 platform version:
https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html